# Dynamic RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a way to combine this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (user-x/project/www)
RewriteRule ^.*$ /user-x/project/www/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (user-y/project/www)
RewriteRule ^.*$ /user-y/project/www/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (user-z/project/www)
RewriteRule ^.*$ /user-z/project/www/index.php [NC,L]
```

To a "dynamic" rule which works for "n" users?

I had this in mind:

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)/project/www/index.php$ /$1/project/www/index.php [NC,L]
```

Unfortunately the first argument of RewriteRule doesn't include the whole path when matching with a regex.

Any ideas?

Edit: .htaccess file is located in the "www" directory.

Comment: If it is at `www` dir, then you have one .htaccess file for each user?

Comment: Yes, but it's a check out from a svn repo. I want the htaccess file in the repo, because there are also configs in it for staging and production environments.

Comment: Just replace this part `^/([a-z]+)/` with `^([^/]+)/` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're trying to match against `%{THE_REQUEST}`, which is actually the request and not the URI. But you can combine like:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (user-x|user-y|user-z)/project/www
RewriteRule ^ /%1/project/www/index.php [L]
```

But the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable actually looks something like this:

```
GET /some/path/maybe/a/user-x/project/www/and/some/more/stuff HTTP/1.1
```

And the above condition would match the above request. Otherwise, you can be more specific about wat to match:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(user-x|user-y|user-z)/project/www/?($|\ )
RewriteRule ^ /%1/project/www/index.php [L]
```